# Night - lights for social welfare

Tags: imagery, europe

I want to to find the social welfare and the population density for Europe and Africa with night-lights. Is there any site where I can find images with good resolution (I only think VIIRS)??? I have never worked with night-lights so I don' t know much.

Comment: I think that the VIIRS Nightlights data is the only consistent source of nightlight data. As such, I don't think that you can get better resolution data from anywhere.

Comment: I work in the collegue a bit with night images and my latest info where that VIIRS are the best resolution in night time for the moment (it a 2 year old info, so i could be wrong)

[link](http://journals.sfu.ca/apan/index.php/apan/article/download/7/pdf_7)